# how to Append column value from one CSV file to another from a certain point in the file

Tags: r, csv, svm

I have two files 
1. Cleaned.csv, columns: SVM_LABEL, text( having 1:499 training data, 500:650 test data)
2. result.csv, columns:SVM_LABEL, SVM_PROB( SVM_LABEL for test data)

I want to append the SVM_LABEL obtained in result.csv to Cleaned.csv from 500th row.
How can i do that in R?
Any suggestion will be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

You can subset data in your merge, using your example specifically:

```
 newdata=merge(cleaned[500:nrow(cleaned),],result,by='SVM_LABEL')
```

Comment: this checks the  same values in both the files for SVM_LABEL and merges rite? i want to simply merge two files with appending it from 500th row for the SVM_LABEL values